# how to keep alive activity with notification and runnable every second

Tags: java, android, service

I have an activity that demonstrates information ping results about servers. This job is done every second with runnable like below code:

```
pingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          pingMethod();
          resultsNotification();
          handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
```

on the other hand, I have to show some results in the notification realtime and I did it, But there is a problem, that in the first when the device was locked after 10 min app and activity was destroyed by OS and just notification stopped in a stagnant status. then I tried to fix it with below code:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
wl.release();
```

Actually, I used wl.release(); like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        wl.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

It got better when I did it, but when the device was locked this again happened after some hours.
Right now I don't know exactly how can I control these services (background(Runnable) and foreground(Notification) ) together for keeping alive activity for a long time such as two or three days or even more.

Comment: try to make your service foreground and keep updating notification without creating a new one.

Comment: you can't and should not try to make Activity live long. If you need to do something in background, use a service (and show the results in activity). If you need to do that for long time - use a `foreground service`

Answer (score 0):

First up you shouldn't be using an Activity to do this kind of work a Service is the recommended approach. To do this kind of work intelligently you have a number of options with the Android framework, most recently the new WorkManager component. These services should offer you the ability to control when your background work is scheduled - e.g. only running when a valid network connection is present and by allowing you to select a period when the work should run.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced

Secondly, polling every second will have a drastic impact on battery life - if you do this most likely your app will be flagged as a bad citizen and be a likely candidate for uninstalling.

You should consider whether polling in general is the best option for your users. Using cloud messaging would improve the amount of work your app needs to do to, i.e. you could just push out a notification when the server data changes, which avoids you having to do the manual polling. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/